Unable to redirect from Login Page to dashboard
I am building a simple application (currently just working at the authentication flow). I already have login and registration working at the backend and some visual UI to input data in order to make it work. Assume the registration and login works since it is what happens now.
The issue I am facing is more related to routing, I need to do 2 things:

When user access "/" I verify if the user is authenticated, if he is it keeps the user at / otherwise it sends him to "/login"

After login I want to send the user to the "/" page, this step is failing, and I am not sure why it is happening.


This is the code I have at the moment:
Routes.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate, Route, Routes, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthController } from './controllers/AuthController';
import { ElfMetter } from './components/ElfMetter';
import { useAppDispatch } from './state/hooks';
import { http } from './config/http';
import { setUser } from './state/slices/globalSlice';

export const AppRoutes = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAuth = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const result = await http.get('whoAmI', {
          withCredentials: true,
        });

        dispatch(setUser(result.data));
        setIsAuthorized(true);
      } catch (err) {
        setIsAuthorized(false);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchAuth();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!isAuthorized) {
    navigate('/login');
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<ElfMetter />} path="/" />
      <Route element={<AuthController />} path="/login" />
      <Route element={<AuthController isRegister />} path="/register" />
    </Routes>
  );
};


This is my AuthControler file where I control the registration and Login
import React from 'react';
import AuthRegister from '../components/AuthRegister';
import AuthLogin from '../components/AuthLogin';
import { http } from '../config/http';
import { redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

interface IAuthControllerProps {
  isRegister?: boolean;
}

export const AuthController = ({ isRegister }: IAuthControllerProps) => {
  const loginRequest = async (
    email: FormDataEntryValue | null,
    password: FormDataEntryValue | null,
    options?: { withCredentials: boolean },
  ) => {
    try {
      await http.post(
        '/login',
        {
          emailOrUsername: email,
          password,
        },
        options,
      );
      redirect('/');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const handleRegistration = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target as HTMLFormElement;
    const formData = new FormData(target);

    const username = formData.get('username');
    const email = formData.get('email');
    const password = formData.get('password');

    try {
      await http.post('/register', {
        username,
        email,
        password,
      });

      await loginRequest(email, password);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const handleLogin = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target as HTMLFormElement;
    const formData = new FormData(target);

    const emailOrUsername = formData.get('emailOrUsername');
    const password = formData.get('password');

    await loginRequest(emailOrUsername, password, { withCredentials: true });
  };

  return isRegister ? (
    <AuthRegister onSubmit={handleRegistration} />
  ) : (
    <AuthLogin onSubmit={handleLogin} />
  );
};


The redirect('/'); is not working properly since it keeps the user at the same page instead of sending him to the main page again. Any advice on this?
I also tried to return a Navigation component directly inside the AuthController, but it also didnt work properly :/
Appreciate the help!
Thanks!
I expect to have a brief explanation about why it doesnt work and what I can do to improve the current workflow to make it work. Appreciate any help!
